# Kendo UI Grid binding with scaffolding/CRUD operations to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid

First of all, I'm a complete novice with Kendo UI/Client side code.

I'm used to using standard MVC scaffolding to display my tables (Entity first):

```
  +------------------------------------+
  | +--------------------------------+ |
  | |___ID___|__Name_|__price_|______| |
  | |        |       |        |CRUD  | |
  | |        |       |        |      | |
  | |        |       |        |      | |
  | |        |       |        |      | |
  | |        |       |        |      | |
  | +--------+-------+--------+------+ |
  +------------------------------------+
```

where the CRUD part shows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
```

In terms of the Kendo Grid, however, I'm at a loss as to incorporating their Actions with these.

I.e. How am I meant to be 'adding' their inline or (preferably) [pop up](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup) editing with this?

My model is a database table:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.TableName>
```

I am currently giving the table an ID and using the following script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#myTablesID').kendoGrid({
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: true,
            groupable:true,
            pageable: true,
            selectable: "row",
            filterable: true,
            resizable: true,
            dataSource: { pageSize: 10 }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is there a 'standard' way of using the MVC scaffolding with pop up editing in the Kendo Grid?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5/Javascript source in this link is a very good place to start.
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-popup

You have to set up matching controller actions.
Refer to the Editing_PopupController.cs example in the ASP.NET MVC source section

Comment: To be honest, that *was* the first place I started. But It doesn't say what/where the **productService** is defined :( Unless it's just the db.TableName.Remove / etc?

Comment: I have used the MVC HtmlHelpers that come with Kendo (Kendo.Mvc.dll). The editing_popup.cshtml example shows how to use them and more in line with the MVC scaffold way of doing things.

Comment: I am realizing now that your question is more about looking for a way to bake it into the code that scaffolding spits out. I haven't come across where this has been done. I am also realizing that I am not being much help. Sorry.

Comment: That's ok, but I'm certain i'm missing something here - After all, telerik advertise their product to be full compatible with MVC, so i'm slightly abashed as to why this doesn't seem to be obvious

Comment: Well, you right about what you said about any *productService* lines of code from the example is supposed to be replaced with your `db.TableName.Add(entity); db.SaveChanges();` lines of code.